# Pandas DataFrame: value in a column based on previous values in another column for same value in a third column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ref1': [1,1,3,7,7],
    'ref2': [1,2,1,1,2],
    'value': [1,2,3,5,6],
})

df

    ref1    ref2    value
0   1       1       1
1   1       2       2
2   3       1       3
3   7       1       5
4   7       2       6
```

I want to add the column `new_value` and obtain this:

```
    ref1    ref2    value   new_value   my_comment
0   1       1       1       NaN         no prev ref1
1   1       2       2       NaN         no prev ref1
2   3       1       3       1.0 
3   7       1       5       3.0 
4   7       2       6       NaN         no same ref2 @ ref1==3
```

following these rules:

1. `new_value` is `value` for the same `ref2` and previous `ref1` (in an ordered list like `[1,3,7]`), else
2. `NaN`

Comment: Why isn't the last `NaN` a `1`?

Comment: @mozway because I want the `value` of `ref2==2` (same ref2) when `ref1==3` (previous ref1 in list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `1, 3, 7` are in order, you can pivot, shift, stack back to get the shifted values, then merge:

```
df.merge(df.pivot(index='ref1', columns='ref2', values='value')
           .shift().stack().reset_index(name='new_value'),
         on=['ref1','ref2'], how='left'
)
```

Output:

```
   ref1  ref2  value  new_value
0     1     1      1        NaN
1     1     2      2        NaN
2     3     1      3        1.0
3     7     1      5        3.0
4     7     2      6        NaN
```

**Note** If there are duplicate combinations of `ref1, ref2`, `pivot` will fail. In which case, you want to enumerate the pairs:

```
df.merge(df.assign(enum=df.groupby(['ref1','ref2']).cumcount())
           .pivot(index=['enum','ref1'], columns='ref2', values='value')
           .shift().stack()
           .reset_index(level='enum', drop=True)
           .reset_index(name='new_value'),
         on=['ref1','ref2'], how='left'
)
```